# Upload multiple images with express.js and multer

Tags: express, multer

I am working on uploading multiple images and those images are gonna be store under this public/images directory. The code works perfectly when I only upload a single image.

However when I upload multiple images, it fails.

**Error when I upload multiple images** :

`TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Array`

This is my frontend logic of uploading multiple image files:

```
   <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
      <label className={styles.fileLabel}>
        Upload
        <input
         className={styles.fileInput}
         type="file"
         name="file"
         multiple="multiple"
         accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/jpg"
         onChange={handleFileChange}
        />
      </label>
      <button className={styles.send} type="submit">Post</button>
   </form>
```

The handle submit logic :

```
const handleSubmit = async(e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData();
    if (fileArray.length !== 0) {
      
      const filenames = []; // Create an empty array to store filenames

      fileArray.forEach((currentFile) => {
        const fileName = Date.now() + currentFile.name;
        data.append("name", fileName);
        data.append("file", currentFile);
      });
      try {
        console.log(data);
        await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/upload", data);
      } catch (err) {}
    }
```

Backend middleware and storage :

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "public/images");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    //cb(null,  file.originalname);
    const fileName = req.body.name; // Use the filename sent from the frontend
    cb(null, fileName);
  },
});

const upload = multer({storage});
app.post("/api/upload", upload.array("file",10),(req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.files); // Logs any files
    return res.status(200).json("File uploded successfully");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});
```

Output when I upload a single file :

My backend console display (req.files) :

```
[   {
    fieldname: 'file',
    originalname: 'profile.jpg',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    destination: 'public/images',
    filename: '1686559793316profile.jpg',
    path: 'public\\images\\1686559793316profile.jpg',
    size: 100183   }
```

]